# Cypher: Neighbours of which all neighbours satisfy an inequality

Tags: cypher

Let's say you have a database that satisfies the following scheme:

```
(person {name:string, budget:int})
(person)-[:FRIEND]-(person)
```

How would one query the following in Cypher?

*"Give all friends of Alice of whom holds that ALL their friends have a budget that is greater than 100."*

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following query in Cypher for this:

```
MATCH (alice {name:"Alice"})
MATCH (alice)-[:FRIEND]-(f)
MATCH (f)-[:FRIEND]-(person)
WITH f, collect(person) as friends
WHERE ALL(x in friends WHERE x.budget > 100 )
RETURN f, friends
```